Code not working as shown on the original website
I copied this tree viewer from codepen.io, trying to use it on my static website. What is strange is that it doesn't work as shown on codepen.io. Ideally we should be able to expand and collapse the sub-directories, but after I copied the code into my own webpage, all the sub-directories are just listed alongside the parent folder.
This is what it should look like before expanding:

But this is what I actually got on my own website:

Below is the code snippet copied from codepen.io, you could try the link at the beginning to see how it works on codepen.io.


/* shorthand functions (createElement is defined at bottom)*/
const div = (props, ...children) => createElement("div", props, ...children);
const ul = (props, ...children) => createElement("ul", props, ...children);
const li = (props, ...children) => createElement("li", props, ...children);
const i = (props, ...children) => createElement("i", props, ...children);
const span = (props, ...children) => createElement("span", props, ...children);
const header = (props, ...children) =>
  createElement("header", props, ...children);
const p = (props, ...children) => createElement("p", props, ...children);
const section = (props, ...children) =>
  createElement("section", props, ...children);
const button = (props, ...children) =>
  createElement("button", props, ...children);

/* File */

const File = ({ name }) => {
  return div(
    { className: "file" },
    i({ className: "material-icons", style: "opacity: 0;" }, "arrow_right"),
    i({ className: "material-icons" }, "insert_drive_file"),
    span(null, name)
  );
};

/* Folder */

const openedFolderIcon = "folder_open";
const closedFolderIcon = "folder";
const openedArrowIcon = "arrow_drop_down";
const closedArrowIcon = "arrow_right";

function changeOpened(event) {
  const folderHeader = event.target.classList.contains("folder-header")
    ? event.target
    : event.target.parentElement;
  const opened = folderHeader.getAttribute("opened") == "true";
  const newOpened = !opened;

  let icons = folderHeader.querySelectorAll(".material-icons");
  icons.forEach(icon => {
    if (/arrow/i.test(icon.textContent)) {
      icon.textContent = newOpened ? openedArrowIcon : closedArrowIcon;
    } else {
      icon.textContent = newOpened ? openedFolderIcon : closedFolderIcon;
    }
  });

  try {
    const sibling = folderHeader.nextElementSibling;
    if (newOpened) {
      sibling.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      sibling.classList.add("hide");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(`No sibling of elem ${folderHeader} found ...`);
  }

  folderHeader.setAttribute("opened", newOpened);
}

const Folder = (props, ...children) => {
  const opened = props.opened || false;
  const arrowIcon = opened ? openedArrowIcon : closedArrowIcon;
  const folderIcon = opened ? openedFolderIcon : closedFolderIcon;
  const folderName = props.name || "unknown";

  return div(
    { className: "folder" },
    header(
      {
        onClick: changeOpened,
        className: "folder-header",
        opened: opened
      },
      i({ className: "material-icons" }, arrowIcon),
      i({ className: "material-icons" }, folderIcon),
      span(null, folderName)
    ),
    ul({ className: opened ? "" : "hide" }, ...children)
  );
};

/* TreeView */

const TreeView = () => {
  return section(
    { className: "container" },
    Folder(
      { name: "src" },
      Folder({ name: "myTest.js" }, File({ name: "whatup.js" })),
      File({ name: "justASimpleFile.css" })
    ),
    File({ name: "project.json" })
  );
};

const app = document.querySelector("#treeView");
app.appendChild(createElement(TreeView));

/* My react-clone mini library */

function appendChildren(parent, children) {
  for (let child of children) {
    if (!child) continue;
    switch (typeof child) {
      case "string":
        const el = document.createTextNode(child);
        parent.appendChild(el);
        break;
      default:
        parent.appendChild(child);
        break;
    }
  }
}
function setStyle(el, style) {
  if (typeof style == "string") {
    el.setAttribute("style", style);
  } else {
    Object.assign(el.style, style);
  }
}
function setClass(el, className) {
  className.split(/\s/).forEach(element => {
    if (element) {
      el.classList.add(element);
    }
  });
}
function setProps(el, props) {
  const eventRegex = /^on([a-z]+)$/i;
  for (let propName in props) {
    if (!propName) continue;

    if (propName === "style") {
      setStyle(el, props[propName]);
    } else if (propName === "className") {
      setClass(el, props[propName]);
    } else if (eventRegex.test(propName)) {
      const eventToListen = propName.replace(eventRegex, "$1").toLowerCase();
      el.addEventListener(eventToListen, props[propName]);
    } else {
      el.setAttribute(propName, props[propName]);
    }
  }
}

//type, [props], [...children] 
function createElement(type, props, ...children) {
  if (typeof type === "function") {
    return type(props);
  } else {
    const el = document.createElement(type);
    if (props && typeof props === "object") {
      setProps(el, props);
    }
    if (children) {
      appendChildren(el, children);
    }
    return el;
  }
}
/* Tree View */
#treeView {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-right: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#treeView span {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
#treeView i {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* File */
.file {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Folder */
.folder {
  display: block;
}
.folder-header {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* z-index: 999; */
}

.folder-header:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.folder > ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m4" id="treeView">
  </div>
</div>



As you can see, this code doesn't work on SO either.
What am I doing wrong? How to make this code snippet work as illustrated?

In the codepen example, the hide class set on those elements applies display: none. Your example sets the class on the elements - but there is no corresponding rule in your stylesheet, to apply any formatting based on it. The codepen has the materialize CSS embedded as well, you're missing that.

@CBroe So I think a simple solution would be to add .hide { display:none !important } in the CSS file.

You didn't include the library that they are using on codepen


/* shorthand functions (createElement is defined at bottom)*/
const div = (props, ...children) => createElement("div", props, ...children);
const ul = (props, ...children) => createElement("ul", props, ...children);
const li = (props, ...children) => createElement("li", props, ...children);
const i = (props, ...children) => createElement("i", props, ...children);
const span = (props, ...children) => createElement("span", props, ...children);
const header = (props, ...children) =>
  createElement("header", props, ...children);
const p = (props, ...children) => createElement("p", props, ...children);
const section = (props, ...children) =>
  createElement("section", props, ...children);
const button = (props, ...children) =>
  createElement("button", props, ...children);

/* File */

const File = ({ name }) => {
  return div(
    { className: "file" },
    i({ className: "material-icons", style: "opacity: 0;" }, "arrow_right"),
    i({ className: "material-icons" }, "insert_drive_file"),
    span(null, name)
  );
};

/* Folder */

const openedFolderIcon = "folder_open";
const closedFolderIcon = "folder";
const openedArrowIcon = "arrow_drop_down";
const closedArrowIcon = "arrow_right";

function changeOpened(event) {
  const folderHeader = event.target.classList.contains("folder-header")
    ? event.target
    : event.target.parentElement;
  const opened = folderHeader.getAttribute("opened") == "true";
  const newOpened = !opened;

  let icons = folderHeader.querySelectorAll(".material-icons");
  icons.forEach(icon => {
    if (/arrow/i.test(icon.textContent)) {
      icon.textContent = newOpened ? openedArrowIcon : closedArrowIcon;
    } else {
      icon.textContent = newOpened ? openedFolderIcon : closedFolderIcon;
    }
  });

  try {
    const sibling = folderHeader.nextElementSibling;
    if (newOpened) {
      sibling.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      sibling.classList.add("hide");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(`No sibling of elem ${folderHeader} found ...`);
  }

  folderHeader.setAttribute("opened", newOpened);
}

const Folder = (props, ...children) => {
  const opened = props.opened || false;
  const arrowIcon = opened ? openedArrowIcon : closedArrowIcon;
  const folderIcon = opened ? openedFolderIcon : closedFolderIcon;
  const folderName = props.name || "unknown";

  return div(
    { className: "folder" },
    header(
      {
        onClick: changeOpened,
        className: "folder-header",
        opened: opened
      },
      i({ className: "material-icons" }, arrowIcon),
      i({ className: "material-icons" }, folderIcon),
      span(null, folderName)
    ),
    ul({ className: opened ? "" : "hide" }, ...children)
  );
};

/* TreeView */

const TreeView = () => {
  return section(
    { className: "container" },
    Folder(
      { name: "src" },
      Folder({ name: "myTest.js" }, File({ name: "whatup.js" })),
      File({ name: "justASimpleFile.css" })
    ),
    File({ name: "project.json" })
  );
};

const app = document.querySelector("#treeView");
app.appendChild(createElement(TreeView));

/* My react-clone mini library */

function appendChildren(parent, children) {
  for (let child of children) {
    if (!child) continue;
    switch (typeof child) {
      case "string":
        const el = document.createTextNode(child);
        parent.appendChild(el);
        break;
      default:
        parent.appendChild(child);
        break;
    }
  }
}
function setStyle(el, style) {
  if (typeof style == "string") {
    el.setAttribute("style", style);
  } else {
    Object.assign(el.style, style);
  }
}
function setClass(el, className) {
  className.split(/\s/).forEach(element => {
    if (element) {
      el.classList.add(element);
    }
  });
}
function setProps(el, props) {
  const eventRegex = /^on([a-z]+)$/i;
  for (let propName in props) {
    if (!propName) continue;

    if (propName === "style") {
      setStyle(el, props[propName]);
    } else if (propName === "className") {
      setClass(el, props[propName]);
    } else if (eventRegex.test(propName)) {
      const eventToListen = propName.replace(eventRegex, "$1").toLowerCase();
      el.addEventListener(eventToListen, props[propName]);
    } else {
      el.setAttribute(propName, props[propName]);
    }
  }
}

//type, [props], [...children] 
function createElement(type, props, ...children) {
  if (typeof type === "function") {
    return type(props);
  } else {
    const el = document.createElement(type);
    if (props && typeof props === "object") {
      setProps(el, props);
    }
    if (children) {
      appendChildren(el, children);
    }
    return el;
  }
}
/* Tree View */
#treeView {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-right: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#treeView span {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
#treeView i {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* File */
.file {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Folder */
.folder {
  display: block;
}
.folder-header {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* z-index: 999; */
}

.folder-header:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.folder > ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m4" id="treeView">
  </div>
</div>



